# Using netbeans GUI designer to design for projects outside of netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm writing a plugin for another Java program in which I need to create a GUI. I've got the GUI designed in Netbeans, but I would like to put all of the elements in a panel instead of a frame. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: OK - what is the problem/question?  I don't use NetBeans, but I'm sure I have seen (the horrid) NetBeans code (it churns out) used for a JPanel rather than a JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file type exists in the menu at

`File >> New File >> Java >> Swing GUI Forms >> JPanel Form`

The sources auto generated should be specific to swing, not netbeans. The `.form` file will probably only work with the Netbeans Matisse GUI builder though.

Comment: Good answer.  It is true the .form will only work with the NetBeans GUI builder.  If the .java code is directly edited, the GUI builder can not be used on the changed code.